# Display archive by year and months in horizontal manner

Tags: wordpress

In WordPress archive page I am trying to show the archives according to year and month in horizontal manner like [this](https://www.tothenew.com/blog/2018/01/). I have been able to display years horizontally but for some reason months are not showing as intended. The issue is all the months of all the years are displaying and overlapping each other like in the image below.
[image]

What I intend to achieve is only the months for the selected year should show and if any other year is clicked its respective months should show up.

So here is my code below. Please have a look and tell me what's missing:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$limit = 0;
$year_prev = null;
$months = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(post_date) AS month, YEAR(post_date) AS year, COUNT(id) AS post_count FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_date <= NOW() AND post_type = 'post' GROUP BY month, year ORDER BY post_date DESC");

echo "<ul>";
foreach($months as $month)
{
    $year_current = $month->year;

    if($year_current != $year_prev)
    {
        if($year_current != date('Y'))
        {
            ?>
            </ul>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            <li>
                <!-- years -->
                <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/blog/<?php echo $month->year; ?>/"><?php echo $month->year; ?></a>
                <!-- months -->
                <ul class="archive-list" style="display:block;">
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/blog/<?php echo $month->year; ?>/<?php echo date("m", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)); ?>">
                        <?php echo date_i18n("M", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month->month, 1, $month->year)); ?>
                        </a>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </li>
                    <?php
                    $year_prev = $year_current;

                    }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its looks like there is an absolute position causing this to happen.

try something like `ul li {position: unset;}`